# How to call AMD typescript function in html page?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, requirejs

I want to use the below script that modularized using "AMD" in my html page.
I tried something with Require.js, but getting this error

Uncaught ReferenceError: getByColor is not defined
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick ((index):1)

outmod.js

```
    define("enums", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var color;
    (function (color) {
        color[color["red"] = 0] = "red";
        color[color["green"] = 1] = "green";
        color[color["blue"] = 2] = "blue";
    })(color || (color = {}));
    exports.color = color;
});
define("ibook", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
});
define("mymod", ["require", "exports", "enums"], function (require, exports, enums_1) {
    "use strict";
    Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
    var books = [{ id: 1, title: "book1", author: "krish", available: true, colour: enums_1.color.red },
    { id: 2, title: "book2", author: "pink", available: false, colour: enums_1.color.green },
    { id: 3, title: "book3", author: "sach", available: false, colour: enums_1.color.blue },
    { id: 4, title: "book4", author: "sal", available: true, colour: enums_1.color.red }
    ];
    function getByColor(mycolor) {
        books.filter(function (bk) {
            if (bk.colour === enums_1.color[mycolor]) {
                console.log(bk);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: '/',
    deps: ['outmod'],
    paths: {

    }
});
```

html page

```
<script data-main="main" src="require.js"></script>
    <input type="button" value="Module Demo!" onclick="getByColor('red');"/>
```

Comment: you can't just call the methods from a module, you have to load it first.

Comment: @toskv How to load it?